# SQL Server 2008 cannot define decimal type with 4 decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 express, any reason??
however, if i convert to decimal(6,4) is work. e.g. Select CONVERT(decimal(6,4),'1.1234');
thanks you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decimal(Precision, Scale). The Precision number control the maximum number of digits on the left side of the period. The Scale specifies the maximum number of digits on the right side.

If you want 3 digits before decimal and 4 after decimal then

```
rate    decimal(7, 4)
```

Comment: Precision controls the maximum number of digits, period.  The text part of your answer is wrong, but your code example is correct.

Comment: @Jon thanks. Can you please write down the correct description?

Comment: You already have it right in your code, and Sadat has quoted it below: the first value controls the maximum number of digits.  The second value specifies the maximum number of digits on the right.  So a DECIMAL(7, 4) could be 123.4567.

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal(x,y)

x: total number of digits(max)
y: number of digits after decimal point(max)

thats why y<=x
```